# Gcc : ld cannot find -lc

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to compile a simple program with

```
gcc main.c
```

and gcc throws me the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

I'm on Linux Mint 17.2, gcc version is 4.8.4

Comment: does `apt-get install build-essential` want to install lots of things?

Comment: It installed 9 packages and now it works perfectly ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ld`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) is the linker, i.e. the program that ties together the code that you wrote with the preexisting library code. `-lc` means the library which is stored in the file `libc.a` and which is linked because the option `-lc` is passed to the linker.

`libc` is the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), which is automatically linked in every program unless you explicitly request that it isn't (which is rarely done except for such things as compiling libc itself, since you pretty much can't do anything without libc, and you definitely can't do anything that's vaguely portable).

You need the package that provides `libc.a`. You can find it with `apt-file search /libc.a` (you'll need to install `apt-file` first, and initialize it by running `sudo apt-file update`). The package is called `libc6-dev`; most development packages in Debian and derivatives (including Ubuntu, Mint, etc.) are called `libNAME#-dev` where NAME is the name of the library collection (which is not always the name of the specific library you link with, for example the `libc6` package includes other libraries such as `libm`) and # is a version number.

The C standard library is needed to build pretty much anything, so it's a dependency of the [build-essential package](https://packages.debian.org/build-essential), which you should include if you do any compiling.

Comment: The missing library is probably not `libc.a`, which is only needed for linking statically, but `libc_nonshared.a` which is the static part GCC includes when linking dynamically.